# konva stage.toJSON is trimming all Text node when saving file

Tags: json, string, stringify, konvajs

Every Konva Text gets trimmed(all white spaces removed) whenever I try to save the stage to JSON, here's my code :

```
var exportObj = stage.toJSON();
    console.log(exportObj);
    $("<a />", {
        "download": "yearBook.yrb",
        "href" : "data:application/json," + exportObj,
    }).appendTo("body")
            .click(function() {
                console.log("save");
        $(this).remove();
    })[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because of inserting JSON data to HTML (to DOM attribute `href`).

Try to use this for 'href' attribute:
`"data:application/json;base64," + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(exportObj)))`

```
var exportObj = stage.toJSON();
console.log(exportObj);
$("<a />", {
    "download": "yearBook.json",
    "href" : "data:application/json;base64," + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(exportObj))),
}).appendTo("body")
        .click(function() {
            console.log("save");
    $(this).remove();
})[0].click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @lavrton, but it gives an error on console: InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character, and btw what's the btoa?

Comment: Thanks again for your effort, but I actually come up with a work around for this problem yesterday, I replace all white spaces with character _@ so ,  if I load the file I can then replace them back with white spaces. Your code may also be an answer though it encodes the save file to something like this : eyJhdHRycyI6eyJ3aWR0aCI6NjM1LCJoZWlnaHQiOjc2OH0sImNs.... And that I cannot load back the file, still I'm curious if that data can be decoded back so It can be loaded correctly...